# Add Button to Chart

Tags: button, charts, addition

I have a working Excel VBA macro called CreateGraph that generates an Excel chart from existing data. I want to modify CreateGraph such that after the chart is created it adds a button on the chart itself that in turn can be used to call CreateGraph again to make a new (updated) chart.

After much trial and error, google searches, and abundant use of the macro recorder I have cobbled together the following:

```
Sub AddButtonForNewChart()
    Dim MyButton As Button
    Set MyButton = ActiveChart.Buttons.Add(1002750, 138119.25, 589949.25, 238461.75)
    With MyButton
        .Visible = True
        .OnAction = "MainRoutine"
        .Select
        With Selection
            .Characters.Text = "Create New Chart"
            .AutoScaleFont = False
            With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=9).Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .FontStyle = "Regular"
                .Size = 11
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .OutlineFont = False
                .Shadow = False
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        End With
        End With
End Sub
```

This macro runs just fine .... except nothing is produced.  No button anywhere.
Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Eurika!  SMACK (the sound of palm hitting forehead).  It turns out this routine WAS working all along.  The length & width parameters for the Buttons.Add line were the culprit.  They were part of the macro recorder generated effort, but for some unknown reason did not translate well.  When replaced with more reasonable numbers ... viola ... everything worked.  My working script now reads:

Sub AddButtonForNewChart()

```
Dim MyButton As Button
Set MyButton = ActiveChart.Buttons.Add(10, 10, 100, 25)
With MyButton
    .Characters.Text = "Create New Chart"
    .AutoScaleFont = False
    .Visible = True
    .OnAction = "MainRoutine"
End With
```

End Sub